# FIND_IN_SET() alternative?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that currently looks like:

```
SELECT [column a], [column b], [column c], [column d]
FROM [table] 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, column d)
ORDER BY [column a] DESC
```

Where [column d] is of type `varchar`, and holds a set of numbers (ex, `3, 2, 4, 6, 1, 9`). So basically I am trying to return all records where `2` is in its set of numbers. However, when I execute an `EXPLAIN` on the above query, this is my output:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows        Extra
1   SIMPLE      [table] ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL        NULL    500000      Using where; Using filesort
```

This query does not seem to be using any indices during the execution of this query. `[column a]` is the primary key, so there is an index on that column already. Is there any way to utilize an index for this query to run faster? Or is there another way for me to improve the performance of this query?

Answer (score 4):

Alternative: properly normalize the schema.

FIND_IN_SET is *not* [Sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) and the index *cannot* be used.

Comment: So is there a way to create an index on `[column d]`? I was thinking of creating a `FULLTEXT` index since it is of type `varchar`

Comment: wow first time I hear *sargable*, are you the one who created the wiki page ;-)

Comment: @YiweiG It won't be used by FIND_IN_SET; I don't recommend proceeding down that path; a FULLTEXT index requires use of the corresponding operators/functions.

Comment: @user2864740 right, I got much from your answer. Sorry, I meant creating the index as well as changing the query.

Comment: @YiweiG I don't know how such a query/plan would turn out - feel free to try it (and verify it has the correct behavior). I recommend adding in another relation table to handle the multiplicity - it's how SQL was designed to be used.

Comment: @ring0 I blame another SO answer I read awhile ago (maybe from the wiki page's author) .. wish I could take credit xD

Answer (score 3):

One possible optimization is to define `[column d]` as type `SET`. As [documentation says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html):

> MySQL stores SET values numerically, with the low-order bit of the
>   stored value corresponding to the first set member. If you retrieve a
>   SET value in a numeric context, the value retrieved has bits set
>   corresponding to the set members that make up the column value.

Here's a quick and simple example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `tbl_name` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `set_col` set('a','b','c','d') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `set_col_idx` (`set_col`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tbl_name` (`set_col`) VALUES
('a'),
('b'),
('c'),
('d'),
('a,b'),
('a,c'),
('a,d'),
('b,c'),
('b,d'),
('c,d'),
('a,b,c'),
('a,b,d'),
('a,c,d'),
('b,c,d'),
('a,b,c,d');
```

A column `set_col` specified as `SET('a','b','c','d')` have members with following decimal and binary values:

```
╔════════════╦═══════════════╦══════════════╗
║ SET Member ║ Decimal Value ║ Binary Value ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║     'a'    ║       1       ║     0001     ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║     'b'    ║       2       ║     0010     ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║     'c'    ║       4       ║     0100     ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║     'd'    ║       8       ║     1000     ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╩══════════════╝
```

So, if you need to retrive records with value `a,c,d`, it's first, third and fourth member, which is `1 + 4 + 8`, which is `13`.

If you run query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `tbl_name` WHERE `tbl_name`.`set_col` = 13;
```

You'll get:

```
╔════╦═════════════╦══════════╦══════╦═══════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦═══════╦══════╦═════════════╗
║ id ║ select_type ║ table    ║ type ║ possible_keys ║ key         ║ key_len ║ ref   ║ rows ║ Extra       ║
╠════╬═════════════╬══════════╬══════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬═══════╬══════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║ SIMPLE      ║ tbl_name ║ ref  ║ set_col_idx   ║ set_col_idx ║ 1       ║ const ║ 1    ║ Using index ║
╚════╩═════════════╩══════════╩══════╩═══════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩═══════╩══════╩═════════════╝
```

You don't need to manualy get know decimal values of `SET` options – you can use `SUM`, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tbl_name`
WHERE `set_col` = (SELECT SUM(`set_col`)
 FROM `tbl_name`
 WHERE `set_col` IN ('a', 'c', 'd')
);
```

```
╔════╦═════════════╦══════════╦═══════╦═══════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦═══════╦══════╦══════════════════════════╗
║ id ║ select_type ║ table    ║ type  ║ possible_keys ║ key         ║ key_len ║ ref   ║ rows ║ Extra                    ║
╠════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬═══════╬══════╬══════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ PRIMARY     ║ tbl_name ║ index ║ set_col_idx   ║ set_col_idx ║ 1       ║ NULL  ║ 15   ║ Using where; Using index ║
╠════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬═══════╬══════╬══════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ SUBQUERY    ║ tbl_name ║ range ║ set_col_idx   ║ set_col_idx ║ 1       ║ NULL  ║ 3    ║ Using where; Using index ║
╚════╩═════════════╩══════════╩═══════╩═══════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩═══════╩══════╩══════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

1- fulltext index is not a good idea in this case because: 
length of the string you  searching for is small (1) in this case,
   and this won't be found (It is configurable though, but not a good
   idea)

2- If this query is frequent, I suggest changing the tables' structure as follows:

- table1 (col_a PK, col_b, col_c)
- table2 (col_a FK, value_of_sub_d) where value_of_sub_d is one of (2, 3, ...)

In this one-to-many relationship, you can either do a join, or get the PK from table2 where condition is met, and select that ID's row from table1
Example:

```
Select * from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.col_a=t2.col_a WHERE t2.value_of_sub_d=2
```