# Where should I store my black/white lists for login/registration?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am attempting to implement site authentication. I have express routes, a mysql db, and login/register react forms. I am using password-validator (https://www.npmjs.com/package/password-validator) to disable/enable the submit buttons. I'll validate on the server, too. password-validator takes an array of strings to black/whitelist. I'm wondering where I should store these black/whitelists.

I figure I shouldn't store them as json files in the client folder, as it could be altered by the user. Might not matter much if I validate on the server, too, but I'd like to have a single source if I can. I'm unsure if it's possible or prudent to store them in the mysql db. Only other option I can think of is storing them as json on the server. Endpoints with express are ready to go, or I could use socket.io (also ready to go).

Any insight into the best way to do this is appreciated.

Comment: You are right, it's a bad idea to store any kind of whitelist and blacklist data on the front-end, You can use any kind of database to store this information. You need to think about, that what happens if you have multiple instances of the application and what happens when you restart the service. Or your instance on the cloud or server replaced with a new one. So you need a persistent storage for this. So basically a database. If you want to improve on this you can synchronize the data to store in memory on the server as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sándor. I'll look into the best way to store it in my db. Much appreciated.

Comment: I found this helpful if anyone else is having the same problem. [mysql: use SET or lots of columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220238/mysql-use-set-or-lots-of-columns)